# jQuery if checkbox checked calculate fields

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, checkbox

I'm a novice with jQuery and it probably a simple answer but I'm trying to calculate the price and quantity if a checkbox is checked. I loop through a list of items and the user selects the checkbox and enters the quantity and I'd like it to total in the last cell.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="80%">Item</td>
<td width="10%">Price</td>
<td width="10%">Quantity</td>
<td width="10%">Total</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td > <input type="checkbox" name="Extras" value="id" checked="no"></td>
<td >ItemName</td>
<td><cfinput type="text" name="quantity" class="quantity" size="4"></td>
<td>#Extras.Price #</td>
<td><span id="total"></span></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

So far I have the following for my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each (function (){
    // not sure what to put here    
  });

});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you give me and plain example of what you want to achieve? or a live example, because it's not clear where is the quantity and where is the price

Comment: Certainly... here is a live example http://serviceorders.net/test/calculate.cfm 
Hopefully that helps

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Yes the back end is Coldfusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you try to do something like this, check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/vNg9v/2/

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var totalQ = $('#total-q'),
        totalT = $('#total-t'),
        valQ = 0,
        valT = 0;
    $('input:checkbox').change(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            parentRow = $this.closest('tr'),
            totalCell =             parentRow.find('.total'),
            price = parseFloat(parentRow.find('.price').html()),
            quantity = parseFloat(parentRow.find('.quantity').val()),
            total = price * quantity;


        if ($this.prop('checked') === true)
        {
            totalCell.html(total);
            valQ += quantity;
            valT += total;
        }
        else
        {
            valQ -= quantity;
            valT -= total;
            totalCell.text('')   
        }           
        totalQ.html(valQ);
        totalT.html(valT);    
    });
});​
```

Html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="80%">Item</td>
        <td width="10%">Price</td>
        <td width="10%">Quantity</td>
        <td width="10%">Total</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td > 
            <input type="checkbox" name="Extras" value="id" />
        </td>
        <td>ItemName</td>
        <td class="price">12.10</td>
        <td>
            <input name="quantity" class="quantity" size="3" value="0" />
        </td>
        <td class="total"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">TOTAL</td>
        <td id="total-q">0</td>
        <td id="total-t">0</td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

Now this should be exactly what you want?

Comment: That worked great! How can I add the ('input.quantity').change function so it'll update the total when the quantity is changed also?
Thx!

Answer (score 1):

[@erik1001's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13447160/104223) has it all. I'd only make the following changes:

Use 'on' instead of 'click':

```
$('input:type=checkbox').on('click',function(){});
```

Store the function as a variable. So that you can reuse it from multiple events:

```
var runthis = function(){};
$('input:type=checkbox').on('click',runthis);
$('input.quantity').on('change',runthis);
```

Answer (score 0):

This could get real messy, real quick using your current organization. But, you could use combinations of [jQuery.parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [jQuery.children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) to get what you need.

First, change elements to use classes since it sounds like you'll have more than the one row in your example code.

```
<td class="price">#Extras.Price #</td>
<td><span class="total"></span></td>
```

Then, in your `.each` function, bind a click event handler to each checkbox:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each (function (){
    $(this).on('click', function(e) { // bind click event
      var $row = $(this).parent('tr'); // <tr> element
      var total = $row.children('.quantity').val() 
          * parseInt($row.children('.price').val());
      $row.children('.total').html(total);
    });
  });
});
```

I honestly have no idea if jQuery will pickup your `<cfinput>` element.

Answer (score 0):

i try to tidy up a bit your html to be like this :

```
<tr>
   <td> <input type="checkbox" name="Extras" value="id" checked="no" class="theCheckboxItem"></td>
   <td>ItemName</td>
   <td><cfinput type="text" name="quantity" class="quantity" size="4"></td>
   <td class="priceContainer">#Extras.Price #</td>
   <td class="totalContainer"><span id="total"></span></td>
</tr>
```

and the jquery will be like this :

```
  var totalVal = "";
  var qty, price;
  $("input.theCheckboxItem:checked").each (function (){
    qty = $(this).parent().parent().find('.quantity').val();
    price = $(this).parent().parent().find('.priceContainer').text();

    totalVal = parseInt(qty) * parseInt(price);
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.totalContainer').text(totalVal);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have received some good information so far.  The only thing I will add is that, before you attempt to do math with user inputs, make sure the user actually entered a number.

Two answers have mentioned parseInt and parseFloat which may suit your needs.  Just be aware that parseInt("123fred") returns 123.